# Why does entry need the ownership of key?

Tags: rust, hashmap, move-semantics, borrow-checker, ownership

The declaration of [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) is

```
pub fn entry(&mut self, key: K) -> Entry<'_, K, V>  // key is move into entry
```

whereas the one for [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) is

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> where  // k is just a shared reference
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

The [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) interface contains [`key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.key) and [`or_insert_with_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with_key), but both methods merely call for a reference to `key`, so why does `entry` need the ownership of `key` while `get` doesn't?

In other words, what functionality does `Entry` offer by taking the ownership of `key`? If all it offers can be achieved with a shared reference, then I would say requiring ownership is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I figured it out just after I posted the question: I missed [`insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert)

```
pub fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V>
```

So methods like `or_insert` require ownership of `key` to call `insert`.

---

This brings us to another question: why does `HashMap` need the ownership of `key`? Since All it needs is the hash value of `key`, isn't a shared reference sufficient? I guess I should post a separate question to address that, though.

Comment: `HashMap` needs to own a `K` because keys can have the same hash and still need to be differentiated.

Comment: @kmdreko That makes sense! I think a `RefHashMap` which takes references to its keys and/or values can also be helpful when working with immutable structs which are costly to `clone`, though.

Comment: you can do `HashMap<&Key, &Value>` if you want that

Comment: Also while it's probably a consequence of the hashmap storing the keys in order to resolve collisions, the hashmap does store keys and return (references to) them (e.g. default iterator, [`keys`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.keys), [`get_key_value`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_key_value)).

Comment: @Masklinn That's true, but hashmaps can still return references to keys even if they don't take ownership of keys (e.g. by accepting a reference to the key in `insert`)

Comment: @nalzok only by storing the reference, which is just a more complicated and less convenient way of storing the key.